# Manage config of my github repos with the GithubCLI from a Girhub Actions Workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, github-cli

I try to manage my Github Repo Settings from a Github Actions workflow to ensure there are no unwanted changes and everything is consistent across lots of repos (I want to use the same workflow for all repos).

I want to disable the wiki and some other features and found that the Github CLI provides a way to do this. So I came up with:

```yaml
# [...]

permissions:
  contents: write

# [...]

jobs:
  configure-repo:
    name: configure-repo
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Configure repository
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          gh repo edit \
            --enable-discussions \
            --enable-issues \
            --enable-projects \
            --enable-wiki=false \
            --visibility=public
        shell: bash

# [...]
```

The result is always `HTTP 403: Resource not accessible by integration`. I think this is because my `permissions` block only lists `contents`. But I don't know which permissions I should set. The docs https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs list some options, but I don't see any fit. Don't get it to work. Anyone got an idea how I could do this?

UPDATE: I switched my implementation to an API call:

```
gh api --method PATCH \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
    -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
    "repos/sommerfeld-io/${{ github.event.repository.name }}" \
    -F visibility=public \
    -F has_issues=true \
    -F has_projects=true \
    -F has_wiki=false
```

But still I don't get it to work. I always get this error: `Resource not accessible by integration`. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to modify repo A from repo B. This won't work because the GITHUB_TOKEN is [scoped to a single repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#considering-cross-repository-access).

You could achieve what you intend with a Personal access token (discouraged for security reasons) or with a [Github App Token](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/making-authenticated-api-requests-with-a-github-app-in-a-github-actions-workflow)